# Mouse pointer getting stuck

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad

Ok so I'm quite new to ubuntu, I was a manjaro user but I can't seem to make my gpu work on manjaro so I decided to try the regular old ubuntu, everything works great exept for one thing. My mouse cursor seems to sometimes get stuck at like 3/4 of the screen. I can move it on the 3/4 from the left but it gets stuck like there is some invisible wall at this limit, I can force it to go this way if I keep on dragging it but it is really annoying as it makes me lose precious time in some games. I don't really know what is going on and I would like to hear some ideas.

[Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pypM9.jpg)

I've included a imgur link for you guys to see what it looks like.
As you will see it always gets stuck at the same horizontal line.
Thanks a lot,
Bastien

Comment: Try changing the resolution, moving the mouse again to see if it still happens and where and then switching the resolution back, also, change your mousepad or try moving your mouse on a different surface.

Comment: Changing resolution works for a while, just like restarting but problem appears again after 25-30 minutes of using.
Btw I use the touchpad.

Comment: So it's not a mouse?

Comment: I'm talking about the mouse pointer, whether I use a mouse or not is irrelevant because it is definitely software related (Happens with or without a mouse)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to ask, what happens if you connect another external device?