# Mouse pointer stuck for a bit when moving the pointer down on a second monitor

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, mouse, touchpad, mouse-pointer

I use my laptop with a second monitor often, and I see a strange behavior of the mouse pointer when I do. First, let me explain my display set up. I have the displays set up with 2nd (external) monitor on top, and the 1st (laptop) monitor on the bottom. The boundary between monitors is on the top of the 1st (laptop) monitor, and the bottom of the 2nd (external) monitor. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop on the laptop.

The issue is that the mouse pointer gets stuck for a bit when I'm moving the mouse pointer in a downward direction from the top of the 2nd (external) monitor to the bottom of it. The location where this happens is about 2/3 down from the top of the 2nd screen. The mouse pointer will get caught like there is an invisible barrier, until I apply extra pressure to make it pass it. It reminds me of the behavior to make the Ubuntu Dock show when it is hidden. However, I don't have a dock in the second monitor, but I do have the Dash-to-dock bar on the bottom of the 1st (laptop) monitor. Moreover, the pointer does not get stuck when going in an upwards direction, only when going downwards.

This is not the same issue that some people are seeing where the pointer gets stuck between monitors. The pointer gets stuck within a monitor, when it has not changed monitors. However, it is very similar to the issue in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165067/mouse-pointer-getting-stuck) (see video on that post for reference). The behavior is very similar to that post, but there are some differences:

1. It happens when moving the pointer downwards on the 2nd monitor instead of to the right in the 1st monitor.
2. Changing the resolutions does not do anything.
3. It happens regardless of using the laptops touch-pad or an external mouse.

Any help will be really appreciated. This is a really annoying bug.

Comment: This happens to me as well.  Simply rebooting fixes the problem, and it seems to be related to docking/undocking activity, but it's inconsistent / intermittent so I haven't been able to determine contributing factors =/

Comment: I updated to Ubuntu 20.04, and I don't get this issue anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the last software update and a reboot. I don't see the issue anymore ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Same for me. Next time I'll check `xrandr` to see if there are any clues.

Comment: Maybe it was just a glitch or a bug that got fixed, because I haven't had that issue ever since.